# Javascript строка

Tags: javascript

Можно ли поместить значение переменной в такие символы? К примеру.

```
let a = 25;
let z = /a/;
```

То есть значение a поместить  в такие символы! "/25/"
Если помещать в обычную строку значение я могу использовать обратные кавычки, но чтобы поместить их в //, я не могу придумать как это сделать.

Comment: ```let a = 25;
let z = "/" + a + "/";```
Так нельзя?

Answer (score 2):

Вы это имели в виду?

```js
let a = 25;
let z = `/${a}/`;

console.log(z); // выведет /25/
```

Comment: Нет. Немного другое.
В итоге должен получить 
`let z = /25/;`
Мне именно в таком формате нужно, потому что я в бд ищу предметы по совпадению символов(слов)
`const items = await Item.find({name: /и/}).sort({date: -1});`

Comment: @Konstantin попробуйте либо вставить там где name переменную z (из моего кода), либо переменную а таким образом: name: /a/

Comment: @Konstantin Это же регулярное выражение, разве нет? Например, `/a/` - регулярное выражение, состоящее из одного символа `a`.

Comment: @Rikky
Я все пробовал, не получается, когда пишешь `/a/`, то 'a' просто как символ записывается в строку. А ваш пример, я ранее пробовал, так же не работает.
Может быть этот формат регулярное выражение, а не строка?

Comment: @egbro Я уже тоже думаю, что это так, просто мне подсказали такой способ поиска в бд по вхождению символа(слова).

Comment: @Konstantin, смотри ответы в вопросе дубликате